# Explicit DataGrid CellStyle Setter is overridden by an implicit cellstyle in the same context?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, overriding, styles

I have a weird issue with the `DataGrid` in WPFToolkit (.NET 3.5) and the built in version in .NET 4.0:

When creating a keyed `DataGrid`-style with an explicit setter for `CellStyle` to another keyed style it works as suspected. But when also creating an keyless style for `DataGridCell` it will override the explicit `CellStyle`-setter in the `DataGrid`-style. This seems wrong. Is this by design or is it a bug?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CellStyle1" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource CellStyle1}" />
    </Style>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmldata" XPath="data/*">
        <x:XData>
            <data xmlns="">
                <item1 />
                <item2 />
                <item3 />
            </data>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmldata}}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmldata}}" 
          CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle1}" />
```

It seems that the un-keyed style of the `Datagrid` is weaker than the un-keyed style of the `DataGridCell`. It's quite strange, but this is a bit complex question : Unkeyed mother vs Unkeyed child, who should wins ?